# JavaScript convention: How do you assign arguments to the parent scope

Tags: javascript

```
var problemtest = function () {

    var parameters;

    return function (parameters) {
        parameters = parameters;
    }
}

var mysolutiontest = function () {

    var parameters;

    return function (parametersIn) {
        parameters = parametersIn;
    }
}
```

This is more of a JavaScript convention question.

Usually I have code similar to that on top. A function take arguments and assigns it to parent scope. However, I cannot use it as in `problemtest`, as the `parameters` that are arguments hide the `parameters` from `problemtest`.

In OO Programming we can use `this`, but in JavaScript I cannot use `this`, so I usually implement a solution similar to `mysolutiontest`. However, I am not fully satisfied with this solution. Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 4):

If your functions need to share some properties, then assigning them to an object is an elegant and common pattern:

```
var object = {

    property: ['item'],

    methodOne: function() {
        console.log(this.property);
    },

    methodTwo: function() {
        console.log(this.property); 
    }

};

object.methodOne(); // ['item']
object.methodTwo(); // ['item']
```

For further information on how 'this' works within an object - http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/08/30/understanding-javascripts-this/

Comment: +1, but you should probably point out that using `this.property` can cause unexpected behavior to those not familiar with how JS objects work. Example: use `object.methodOne` as an event handler.

Comment: Agreed. Have edited and added Angus Croll's excellent post on the topic

Comment: @LiorCohen—`<... onclick="function(){object.methodOne();}"...>`.

Comment: @RobG I believe Lior was referring more to using an individual method as an event handler with something like `element.addEventListener('click', object.methodOne);` In this instance the context of 'this' would be the element, and not the object as expected.

Comment: Yes, and I was showing a simple method of setting *this* to the expected value, which can also be used with *addEventListener* or *attachEvent*: `element.addEventListener('click', function(){object.methodOne()}); `. It is also possible to use *call* or *apply*.

Comment: To change the context of an event handler you would ideally use the Function.bind() method. e.g. - ``element.addEventListener('click', object.methodOne.bind(this));`` For browsers that don't support it (think IE) you can use a shim - http://goo.gl/4gIDu or latest versions of Modernizr enable it.

Comment: All good points. @RobG: thanks for your feedback, but think about the average developer. Most JS developers I know believe JS is not an OO language :-)

Answer (score 2):

I usually use `_parameters` as a convention. This stems from my Java past. This isn't isolated to your example or to Javascript. Any language that does not force you to qualify the variables of any enclosing scope would lead you to the same problem.

```
var mysolutiontest = function () {
  var _parameters;

  return function (parameters) {
    _parameters = parameters;
  }
}
```

I've also seen people use `p_parameters` to quality function argument names. This is not one of my favorites tho.

```
var mysolutiontest = function () {
  var parameters;

  return function (p_parameters) {
    parameters = p_parameters;
  }
}
```

My 2c.